Default Compose key in Ubuntu 24.04
What is the default Compose key in Ubuntu 24.04?

By default, the compose key is not set up in Ubuntu. So there is no default compose key on Ubuntu. Select the one you prefer. Personally, I use Right Ctrl.

Thx! I wasn't aware of that. And, I must confess, I think the interface is rather confusing, suggesting that there is indeed a 'layout default' for the compose key.

As others have stated, Ubuntu does not set the compose key by default. You can set it by opening settings and going to the "keyboard" category. The Compose Key will be under the "Special Character Entry" section near the bottom of the page.
Open it and uncheck "Use layout default" and you can set the compose key to any of the options.
